# Can't change language on Google Account

Tags: google-account, localization

After using Google from work behind proxy servers, for some reason, they redirected me to Netherlands Google. Ever since, my Google account has been stuck in Dutch no matter where I use my Google account from - at home, my phone, someone else's computer, on Mars... I cannot shake off this Dutch from my account.

I have tried following through this article to no success: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop - my language is set to English, and yes I tried clearing browsing history too, and I have tried using different browsers as well - the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

- sign in to your gmail/google account
- open this: https://myaccount.google.com/language
- change your languages. done
- if it is already set to the desired language (and not working), then change it to any different language, and then back again to the desired language. this way it will reset itself
- if the the select button at the end stays grayed out, open your developer tools and remove the "disabled" property of the button.

Comment: Beside brevity, what are the differences of this instructions of those on the help article linked on the question?

Comment: I opened that link and it says the default language is English - no other languages are defined.

Comment: @LostCrotchet just change it to some other language and then change back on your desired language

Comment: @LostCrotchet glad to hear that

Comment: @Rubén those on the help article linked on the question are outdated and non-valid. this link in my answer is "direct-override" type.

Comment: I think that you should mention that on the question.

Comment: @LostCrotchet:  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I'll accept it when the edit is accepted, because part of the answer is actually in the comments only

Comment: > Change your language. Done
This part is not working for me. I cannot select another language. This is nuts

Comment: It was driving me nuts for a while, since my language was inferred from email domain most likely. Everything was in another language even though the only set language was English. The trick of changing it to another one, then back to English worked for Google Account pages, but I still get the same language when launching other Google products (Docs, Slides, etc.). I'll keep an eye on this, maybe the setting needs to propagate through the servers first.